# Shrink the parent div to the same size as its child div

Tags: html, css

Why div "content" does not **resize the height** according to content in ol?

Also If I remove the *min-height:280px* from content id it removes div completly

[image]

My html and css code:

```
            <aside id="top10-side">
                <div id="title"><span class="icon-stats-bars"></span>Top 10</div>
                <div id="content">
                    <ol>
                        <li><div class="note">9,43</div><span class="name">Test</span></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>          
            </aside>

            aside#top10-side{
                position: relative;
                width: 18%; /* 49.8% */
                right: 15px;
                height: auto;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            div#title {
                position: relative;
                height: 35px;
                background-color: #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                line-height: 35px;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }


            div#content {
                border: 0px solid green;
                position: relative;
                min-height: 280px;
                height: auto;
                width: 90%;
                margin: auto;
            }

            div#content ol{
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                margin: auto 0px auto 0px;
                list-style-type: none;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

            div#content li {
                margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
            }
```

I have already set div#content and aside to auto height, it still not resizing according to ol size

**I changed the ol position to relative and it fixed my problem!**

Comment: What do u want as output? the ol stretch to fill the full height of gray area?

Comment: I want the **content div** to resize according to ol height

Comment: has the `ol` any `float` style? please add extra css styles you have used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer**

just remove the float from `ol`. But if you need to float it, then one of these:

**1.**

```
div#content{ float: left }
```

or

**2.**

```
<div id="content">
    <ol>
        <li><div class="note">9,43</div><span class="name">Test</span></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.clear{ clear: both }
```

### UPDATE

Also, you need to remove the `position: absolute` from `ol`

Comment: Didnt workout, the whole content area disappeared on both ways

Comment: I just noticed ol position was **absolute** switched to **relative** and its working right now, thanks

Comment: to be exact, you need to remove all your defined `position` properties from the attached CSS snippet. you dont need theme at all